# form_for and scopes, rails 3

Tags: scope, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I have a problem due to scopes and the form_for helper in rails 3.
The routes - file looks like this:

```
scope "(/:tab)" do
  resources :article
end
```

The form looks something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@article) %>
   <%= f.label :title %>
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
    etc.
<%end%>
```

The tab - attribute is stored in params[:tab], as a string
My problem is that this genereate wrong urls in the form. How could I get this to work ?
The genreated url article_path(params[:tab], @article) works perfectly fine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer I came up with was quite ugly, but works with both update and create:

```
<%= form_for(@article, :url => (@article.new_record? ? 
    articles_path(params[:tab]) : article_path(params[:tab], @article) do |f| %>
```

Update:
A better solution would be to override the default_url_options-method to something like this:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { :tab => params[:tab] }
end
```

Then the <%= form_for @article do |f| %> could be used, and all urls are correctly generated

Comment: Thanks, I've had the exact same issue and have been looking for a solution to this. I kind of thought there would be a more elegant solution. FYI, looking through the rails helper, it seems to prefer #persisted? to #new_record?, so maybe the best practice would be to do this instead:

`<%= form_for(@article, :url => (@article.persisted? ? article_path(params[:tab], @article) : articles_path(params[:tab]) do |f| %>`

Comment: `default_url_options` in the controller, it can be private.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
<%= form_for [:tab, @article] do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :title %>
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
    etc.
<%end%>
```

Comment: Then it looks for the tab_article_path which is not defined.

Comment: What are the routes generated by your routes.rb file? try "$ rake routes" in a terminal

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the path explicitly:

```
<%= form_for(@article, :url => article_path(@article, :tab => params[:tab]) %>
```

Comment: This seems to work nice on the edit - part, but if I want to use the same form for both new and edit, it fails with the following error in new because the new article has no id

Answer (score 1):

My solution of similar problem with *form_for and scopes* is to define new method in `helpers/<model_name>/<model_name>_helper.rb`, for example mine is sessions_helper.rb which contains

```
module Implant::SessionsHelper
  def sessions_form_path(session)
    session.new_record? ? sessions_path : session_path(session)
  end
end
```

And in my view I made

```
form_for(@session, url: sessions_form_path(@session)) do |f|
```

Problematic routes.rb part

```
scope module: 'implant' do
  resources :sessions
end
```

... and to get managed with `:tab` param you may add it to the helper method.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this to be a really irritating problem and have gotten around this for now with the following monkey patch. Generic like this, it's a little bid off as you're simply passing the entire bag of parameters to polymorphic_url which is what form_for uses under the hood to guess the route. A more concise approach would be to merge just the scope value.

My solution:

https://gist.github.com/1848467

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    module PolymorphicRoutes
      def polymorphic_path(record_or_hash_or_array, options = {})
        begin
            polymorphic_url(record_or_hash_or_array, options.merge(:routing_type => :path))
        rescue Exception => e
            polymorphic_url(record_or_hash_or_array, options.merge(:routing_type => :path).merge(params.reject{|k,v| ["controller", "action"].include? k.to_s}))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In a very similar situation I defined the scope in routes like below:

```
scope :path => ":election_id", :as => "election" do 
  resources :questions
end
```

Now I have helpers like `election_questions_path(@election)`

In the forms I can use:

```
form_for [@election, @question] do |f|
  ...
end
```

In above examples `@election` is an instance of the Election model.

After integrating Friendly_id into this solution I got some pretty urls. For example "http://mydomain.com/elections-2012/questions/my-question"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how far back this goes, but it works on Rails 6. I use:

```rb
<%= form_for(@article, url: [@article, { tab: params[:tab] }]) %>
   <%= f.label :title %>
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
    etc.
<% end %>
```

This works because of the array URL generation syntax. In the `new` case, `@article` is detected as not being persisted and routes to the `POST` route. In the `edit` case, `@article` is detected as being persisted and routes to the `PUT` route with the ID.