# How can I override the method (PUT vs GET) in rails route helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

So I ran into this problem with scoped routes and form_for: [form_for and scopes, rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741979/form-for-and-scopes-rails-3)

My problem is worse though since I don't just want to scope all methods, I want all to be under '/admin' except GET/show.

So my routes.rb has something like this:

```
scope '/admin' do
  resources 'lessons', except: [:show]
end
get "lessons/:id" => "lessons#show", :as => "lesson"
```

Running rake routes does in fact show what I want where both versions of lesson_path differing only by method, PUT vs GET.  So the solution others provide where you do something like this:

```
url = @lesson.persisted? ? lesson_path(@lesson) :  lessons_path
form_for @lesson, url: url do
```

Doesn't work for me because lesson_path(@lesson) will always return the GET path that doesn't have the /admin prefix which still breaks my form.

So what I can't figure out is, can I specify the method in a rails path helper so that it will use the route that starts with /admin?   Or is there a totally different way to get at this?  I know I could cave and simply disambiguate by changing:

```
get "lessons/:id" => "lessons#show", :as => "lesson"
```

to

```
get "lessons/:id" => "lessons#show", :as => "show_lesson"
```

but at this point I'm just curious to know if it is possible and if so what is the "right" way.

Comment: btw, I currently have this working by simply prefixing the url I'm generating in the PUT case manually with '/admin' which is definitely a crappy solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this syntax:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @lesson] do |f| %>
  # form goes here
<% end %>
```

This will build a polymorphic route helper called `admin_lesson_path` if `@lesson` is `persisted?`, or `admin_lessons_path` if it's not. The `admin_lesson_path` helper will be passed the `@lesson` object, so that the route would be something like `admin/lessons/1`. `admin_lessons_path` would generate `/admin/lessons`. The form will then know whether or not to use `POST` or `PUT` depending on if the record is persisted or not.

You can define the routing helpe in your routes file like this:

```
 namespace :admin do
   resources :lessons
 end
```

By namespacing this controller, it has several advantages. One of them is that you can put all your admin-y stuff behind a single namespace and then make everything from that namespace inherit from a base controller:

```
 module Admin
   class LessonsController < BaseController 

   end
 end
```

And then `BaseController` would contain the logic (as a `before_filter`) for restricting whether or not a user can perform actions in that controller.

By putting all your admin-y stuff inside these namespaced controllers, you'll keep all the admin actions in one spot, and all the user-facing actions in another. If you've heard of "separation of concerns", then this is a good case of it.